# Showing feature count when exporting map with qgis2web Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, web-mapping, qgis2web, feature-count

I am trying to include the feature count when using the qgis2web PLugin. I have a point layer and I simply want to show the number of features for each specific field.

[image]

This is what I see in the layer window of QGIS 3.28.11

I would just like to show the same items with feature counts on the web map.

Answer (score 1):

**qgis2web** does not have an option that adds feature count. You have to do this in qgis before exporting by hand.

I asked for help in this forum and you can see the discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/472951/99589). I'll summarize the content of the discussion by adding a way to reset the visibility of the feature count in the name.

To view the feature count **in the name of a single layer** you will need to activate the python console and run this script, indicating the name of your layer

```py
    # imports
    from qgis.core import QgsProject
    
    # getting a layer by its name
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]
    
    # counting features in the layer
    n = layer.featureCount()
    
    # setting up a new name
    layer.setName(f"{layer.name()} [{n}]")
```

You will see that the layer name will capture the feature count. **If the number of features changes you will have to run the command again.**

[image]

If you want to write the feature count **in the name of each vector layer** you will have to run this script

```py
    # imports
    from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
    
    # getting all vector layers' ids in the project 
    ids = [layer.id() for layer in QgsProject().instance().mapLayers().values() if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer)]
    
    # looping over each layer's id
    for id in ids:
        # accessing a layer by its id
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(id)
    
        # getting layer's name
        name = layer.sourceName()
    
        # counting features in the layer
        n = layer.featureCount()
    
        # setting up a new name
        layer.setName(f"{name} [{n}]")
```

If you want to **update** the feature count you will first need to **remove the count** with the following script and then run one of the two scripts written above

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

# getting all vector layers' ids in the project 
ids = [layer.id() for layer in QgsProject().instance().mapLayers().values() if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer)]

# looping over each layer's id
for id in ids:
    # accessing a layer by its id
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(id)

    # getting layer's name
    name = layer.sourceName()

    # checking if the layer name has the pattern " [numero]"
    if " [" in name and name.endswith("]"):
        # removing the " [numero]" part
        new_name = name[:name.rfind(" [")]
        layer.setName(new_name)
```

Comment: Would be nice, if you could include the reference to the original post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/472951/99589

Comment: Thanks, I added it, is it okay to write it like this?

Comment: Thank you andreaordonselli for your response.  I am not familiar with python coding but I will certainly be taking a look.  I suspect I might have a few more questions! :)