# Showing feature count in layer name in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, features, count

I'm looking for a way to write the feature count at the bottom of the Layer Name, is this possible? Is there a variable?

I know about the feature counting functionality built into QGIS and I know the Python Console command that applies feature counting to all groups, layers etc... but I don't need this.

In the image below I would like a variable to be inserted instead of the word HERE which then makes the feature count appear.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a PyQGIS solution.

`QgsVectorLayer` inherits a special method called [`setName()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#aa6cbb1bf0644d7bb82d410ca56557d6c) from the `QgsMapLayer` class.

> Set the display name of the layer.

### If it is a one-time action

#### For a single layer :

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject

# getting a layer by its id
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer("LAYER_ID")

# getting layer's name
name = layer.sourceName()

# counting features in the layer
n = layer.featureCount()

# setting up a new name
layer.setName(f"{name} [{n}]")
```

#### For all vector vector layers shown in the Layers panel :

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

# getting all vector layers' ids in the project 
ids = [layer.id() for layer in QgsProject().instance().mapLayers().values() if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer)]

# looping over each layer's id
for id in ids:
    # accessing a layer by its id
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(id)

    # getting layer's name
    name = layer.sourceName()

    # counting features in the layer
    n = layer.featureCount()

    # setting up a new name
    layer.setName(f"{name} [{n}]")
```

However, if this operation happens more often, one should think of a more programmatic way of showing the feature count in the layer name.

As an alternative one can also proceed with a Python macro, like in this thread: [Is it possible to have dynamic layer names in QGIS project?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131597/is-it-possible-to-have-dynamic-layer-names-in-qgis-project).

---

**References:**

- [Rename layers with PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140749/rename-layers-with-pyqgis-script)
- [Getting feature count of QgsVectorLayer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29500/getting-feature-count-of-qgsvectorlayer-using-pyqgis)
- [Was QgsMapLayerRegistry being removed in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244452/was-qgsmaplayerregistry-being-removed-in-qgis-3)